# How know if a window can be closed with js

Tags: javascript

So as it has been discussed elsewhere, a window can be closed by js using `window.close()` only if it has been opened by a script.

I have a page that offers a button to open a discussion window. The discussion window opens to a new tab with `window.open()`. The discussion page has a button that calls `window.close()`, which closes the discussion window and takes you back to previous tab, so you can continue from where you left off.

The problem is that if someone takes a the url directly to the discussion window, the close button does not work.

Is there a way to detect if the window will be closable with `window.close()`, so I can show the button only if it will work?

Comment: what does `window.close` do if it can't close the window? it might return undefined or give an error, you could check/catch that

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I would assume that you could set  `var chat = window.open()` when you open it form the button, and then set `chat = null` on close. `if(chat !== null)` then the window would have been opened via js

Comment: @atmd I think the OP doesn't want to show the button if its not valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check to see if [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) is not `null`:

> When a window is opened from another window, it maintains a reference
>   to that first window as window.opener. If the current window has no
>   opener, this method returns NULL.  Windows Phone browser does not
>   support window.opener.  It is also not supported in IE if the opener
>   is in a different security zone.

Comment: This is not complete. window.opener is null on window open from an email link, but chrome still allows close.

Comment: @MichaelHanon To be honest, I'd say that's more a bug with Chrome - a window opened from an email is specifically not opened using JavaScript, so it shouldn't allow `window.close` to close it.

Comment: @MichaelHanon In fact, [here's a bug report about this very issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6773) - it's very old (over 9 years), but still not closed, so looks like it's probably a valid bug, but not particularly high priority to fix...!

Comment: Where did the highlighted text come from?

Comment: @MichaelHanon From the page that I linked to.  It was a couple of years ago now, so it might have been rejigged a bit, but it still looks like it’s there in the notes section.

Comment: I appreciate your details on the bug report. After reading the Mozilla documentation i'm convinced this is intended behavior. Mozilla states that a window can only be closed if opened with window.open(). It says nothing about only closing if its the original opener. So checking window.opener is only a half baked solution.

Comment: fyi I was going to remove the down vote but SO locked my vote.

Comment: But if the opener window has closed, window.opener has null setted.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the `window.opener` object, which returns a reference to the window that opened the current window (if it's another window), or `NULL`  if the current window was not opened via JS.

```
if (window.opener) //Show button
```

Comment: That is correct, but James Thorpe beat you to it. Thanks though.

Comment: This is not complete. window.opener is null on window open from an email link, but chrome still allows close

Comment: But if the opener window has closed, window.opener has null setted.